# Single preference screen with disclosure indicator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-preferences

In my android app I need a single preference screen with two items: one leading to a custom non-preference screen and one opening dialog with radio buttons. For the second one, I need a disclosure indicator. I want to save the preference data in my database, not as real preferences (which makes simply no sense in my case). So, I was thinking on making the screen by myself with a simple list fragment. However, I want to stick to the pattern and have the disclosure indicator. Is this possible? Or how could I use a preference fragment and store the user selection on my own?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "disclosure indicator", but just build a custom `Fragment`. I never use `PreferenceFragment` or anything like that, they suck.

Comment: I mean the right arrow in preferences with radio buttons. [Here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NQrPl_1tbdM/T-w6rCNV8PI/AAAAAAAAAko/bZASg_AuFnw/s1600/device-2012-06-28-161309.png) is an example. I build custom items, so adding an image is not a problem, but where can I find the standard image? And that for white background... :?